# Can wp_localize_script be used within a shortcode?

Tags: plugins, shortcode, wp-localize-script

I am developing a plugin, and I would like to make data available to the client-side JS code executed by one of my shortcodes.  `wp_localize_script` seems like the obvious way to do that, but it's not working for me: my script is included, but not the JS data.  The data depends on a value in the querystring, read by the shortcode.  I suspect something to do with the relative timing of scripts and shortcodes in the WP lifecycle.  I have some JS code not used in a shortcode that is happily being provided with data using `wp_localize_script`.

Abbreviated plugin file:

```
function shortcode_orderitem() {

    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    $productData = retrieveSingleProductData($id);
    wp_localize_script('orderitem', 'productData', $productData); //THIS DOES NOT WORK
    return orderItem_buildHTML($productData);
}

function enqueue_general_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('orderitem', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'client/orderitem.js', ['jquery']);

    wp_enqueue_script('mainbag', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'client/mainbag.js', ['jquery']);
    $url = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );
    wp_localize_script('mainbag', 'bagParams', ['url' => $url]); //THIS WORKS
}

add_shortcode('orderitem', "shortcode_orderitem");

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_general_scripts' );
```

Is there some fundamental reason why you can't use `wp_localize_script` directly within a shortcode like that?  Am I missing something else?  Is there a way round it?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried setting `$in_footer` parameter to `true` when enqueueing the script? Scripts are output in `wp_head` by default, you can't localize a script after it's already been output to the page.

Comment: @Milo Well, I feel like an idiot now, because that worked perfectly!  I was sure I'd tried it before with no success, but clearly not.  Thanks, if you turn that into an Answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default parameters for `wp_enqueue_script` will output the script in the `wp_head` function. Shortcodes typically execute later, when main content is being output.

In that case, calling `wp_localize_script` in the Shortcode handler will have no effect, because the script has already been output.

Setting the `$in_footer` parameter to `true` when enqueueing the script will delay script output until `wp_footer`, so `wp_localize_script` will succeed in this case.